# Converting an array of objects into an object of objects

Tags: javascript

Recently, I've been learning on how to retrieve objects from an array and I've had my fair share of converting an array of objects into a singular object of objects, but I couldn't wrap my head around this one!

**dataOfCars.js**:

```
const dataOfCars = [
  {
    id: "car1",
    owner: { license: "license001", name: "driver1" },
    mechanic: [
      {
        id: "mechanic1",
        owner: { license: "license001", name: "driver2" }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "car2",
    owner: { license: "license021", name: "driver2" },
    mechanic: []
  },
  {
    id: "car3",
    owner: { license: "license002", name: "driver2" },
    mechanic: [
      {
        id: "mechanic1",
        owner: { license: "license002", name: "driver2" }
      }
    ]
  }
];
module.exports = dataOfCars;
```

I know there are several examples in regards to this but the output I'm expecting is quite different as it involves nested objects:

```
{
  cars : {
      idOrder : {
          "car1" : {
              id : "car1",
              owner : "owner1",
              mechanic : ["mechanic1", "mechanic2"]
          },
          ...
      },
      result : ["car1", "car2", ...]
  },
  mechanics : {
      idOrder : {
          "mechanic1" : {
              id : "mechanic1",
              owner : "driver2",
          },
          ...
      },
      result : ["mechanic1", ...]
  },
  owners : {
      idOrder : {
          "driver1" : {
              license : "license001",
              name: "driver1",
          },
          ...
      },
      result : ["driver1", "driver2", ...]
  }
}
```

I gave it a go at Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/old-morning-hx9m1. I used `Object.assign({}, ...dataOfCars)` but it only *'spreads'* the whole array, thus returning the final element only per entity. Here's the code at **index.js**:

```
import dataOfCars from "./data.js";
import { normalize, schema } from "normalizr";

const ownerSchema = new schema.Entity("owners");

const mechanicSchema = new schema.Entity("mechanics", {
  mechanic: ownerSchema
});

const carSchema = new schema.Entity("cars", {
  owner: ownerSchema,
  mechanics: [mechanicSchema]
});

/* This method somehow returns the very final element */
const objectPost = Object.assign({}, ...dataOfCars);

const normalizedPost = normalize(objectPost, carSchema);

// The normalized object returning the 2/3 expected entities
console.log(normalizedPost);
```

I'm still relatively new to ES6 and I would love to know how this works out in the end! Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Oh shoot, thanks for pointing it out @CertainPerformance. Fixed it!

Comment: why not include your attempt in the question? it's only a few lines of code

Comment: I was just thinking it could flood the entire page and it might get too congested but will do so everyone can see!

Comment: `it could flood the entire page` - huh? 21 lines of code?

Comment: As per requested good sir!

Comment: Where is `mechanic2` coming from? It's in the output, but not the input.

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguity. Normally, the dataOfCars would consist of several cars, mechanics,etc and I just reduced the data just to have a better readability. But that would be my bad for having that typo lol

Comment: From the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

> Properties in the target object will be overwritten by properties in the sources if they have the same key. Later sources' properties will similarly overwrite earlier ones.

What shape are you hoping for with Object.assign({}, ...dataOfCars)